# Vector projections query

Tags: vectors

For example, if we want vector 'a' in the direction of 'b'. I don't understand how the formula of the scalar resolute multiplied by the unit vector of b (vector resolute) achieves this. This might stem from me not knowing what the scalar resolute actually means, although I know it's just the length but how?

Since the scalar resolute is the multiplication of vector 'a' by the unit vector of 'b'. How doesn't this give us the component of vector 'a' in the the direction of 'b' which is what we want. Why do we have to then multiply by the unit vector of 'b' again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scalar product $\vec a \cdot \vec b$ is the length with sign of the projection of $\vec a$ in the direction of $\vec b$, so **it is a number** not a vector.

If we want **the vector** that is the projection of $\vec a$ on $\vec b$ we have to multiply this number by the unit vecotr in the direction of $\vec b$.